# Create Plottable.js stacked bar chart using the same dataset

Tags: javascript, charts, plottable

I am trying to create stacked bar chart using plottable.js from the same dataset. Is it possible?

Here is my sample dataset

```
var data = [{ x: 0, y: 1, m: 10 },
            { x: 1, y: 1, m: 9 },
            { x: 2, y: 3, m: 5 },
            { x: 3, y: 2, m: 5 },
            { x: 4, y: 4, m: 8 },
            { x: 5, y: 3, m: 7 },
            { x: 6, y: 5, m: 5 }];
```

In the example posted on http://plottablejs.org/components/plots/stacked-bar/, it used two dataset.

```
var plot = new Plottable.Plots.StackedBar()
           .addDataset(new Plottable.Dataset(primaryData).metadata(5))
           .addDataset(new Plottable.Dataset(secondaryData).metadata(3))
           .x(function(d) { return d.x; }, xScale)
           .y(function(d) { return d.y; }, yScale)
           .attr("fill", function(d, i, dataset) { return dataset.metadata(); }, colorScale)
           .renderTo("svg#example");
```

My question is, since I am using the same dataset and I need to change the 'y' function into two distinct functions to something like this:

```
.y(function(d) { return d.y; }, yScale)
.y(function(d) { return d.m; }, yScale)
```

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two different `Plottable.Dataset`s based on the same data.

So start like this:

```
var ds1 = new Plottable.Dataset(data);
var ds2 = new Plottable.Dataset(data);
```

However, later you'll need to distinguish the two datasets to know which attribute to use, so you should add metadata

```
var ds1 = new Plottable.Dataset(data, {name: "ds1"});
var ds2 = new Plottable.Dataset(data, {name: "ds2"});
```

now later, you can reference the name of the dataset to know which value to return in the .y() call

```
plot.y(function(d, i, ds){
  if(ds.metadata().name == "ds1"){
    return d.y;
  }
  else{
    return d.m;
  }
}, yScale);
```